# Is it possible to write kafka consumer batch to create the output to file for every windows

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to write kafka consumer cmd/batch file to output the data into file every window. Assume that each windows has 5 mins. every 5 mins file has to created.

In kafka , can we set the windows as max 30 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

> every 5 mins file has to created

You can use the [HDFS Kafka Connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs) (provided as part of Confluent Platform) can to do this. Installing Hadoop is not required to use it.

Here are the relevant [configuration details for the HDFS Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/configuration_options.html#hdfs-config-options)

```
tasks.max=1
topics=some_topic

connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector

# set to the local filesystem
store.url=file:///path/to/output-dir

# write a file every 5 minutes, one file per-partition
rotate.schedule.interval.ms=300000

# write out JSON-formatted data
format.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.json.JsonFormat
```

[More details on Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/concepts.html)

Otherwise, you need a Kafka Streams process to window 5 minutes worth of data, then output to a new topic. From that topic, you can have a new consumer writing to the console or a file.

> can we set the windows as max 30 minutes?

You can set the topic retention to 30 minutes, sure. The above rotation interval can be as large as you want it.